# Handling negotiation exception in SignalR

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, signalr

I have a Silverlight 5 application accessing a server using SignalR. Most of the times this works fines but now and then when running in debug I get an error during negotiation. I'm thinking that this may be because my local ISS installation runs out of connections.

Anyway, when this occurs, the Unhandled Exception handler in my application is called. I want to change this, so that I can handle the exception local to the initialization of SignalR. I don't want the negotiation error to propagate to my central error handler.

I have a piece of code which looks as follows:

```
     var uri = Application.Current.Host.Source.GetComponents(UriComponents.Scheme | UriComponents.HostAndPort, UriFormat.Unescaped);

     _hubConnection = new HubConnection(uri);
     var hub = _hubConnection.CreateProxy("stuffhub");
     hub.On<Stuff>("Stuff", message => DoStuff());

     var transport = new LongPollingTransport();
     _hubConnection.Start(transport);
```

This code executes fine most of the time, but some times the following exception is handed to my central unhandled excpetion handler a few seconds after the code above has executed.

```
Message: Exception(s) occurred : .
[ Exception(s) occurred : .
[ Exception(s) occurred : .
[ Exception(s) occurred : .
[ System.InvalidOperationException: Server negotiation failed.
   vid SignalR.Client.Transports.HttpBasedTransport.<GetNegotiationResponse>b__0(IResponse     response)
   vid SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.FromMethod[T1,TResult](Func`2 func, T1 arg) ]
 ]
 ]
```

]

The StackTrace of the ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs is:

```
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finalize()
```

Comment: I dont have any experience in C# but isn't there something similar like try{} catch{} ?

Comment: SignalR starts asynchronous tasks in C#. They run on a background thread and hence a try/catch won't work. Normally it's possible to wait for a task to complete and check whether an exception was thrown. The problem here is that the first async tasks spawns a new child async task and then exits. The first task completes fine, but its child task fails. And I can't figure out how to handle the result of the child task failing.

Comment: perhaps let the parent wait until the child returns a callback? in that case you would be able to use the try/catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jon Skeet said, you need to handle the exception from the task returned from Start().

```
var uri = Application.Current.Host.Source.GetComponents(UriComponents.Scheme | UriComponents.HostAndPort, UriFormat.Unescaped);

 _hubConnection = new HubConnection(uri);
 var hub = _hubConnection.CreateProxy("stuffhub");
 hub.On<Stuff>("Stuff", message => DoStuff());

 _hubConnection.Start().ContinueWith(task => 
 {
     if(task.IsFaulted) {
         Debug.WriteLine("Error starting -" + task.Exception.GetBaseException());
     }
 });
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't realize that I had to actually observe the exception by calling task.Exception for the exception not to be propagated to my unhandledexception-handler. I've played with task.IsFaulted code but I never actually accessed the exception that way. I wonder if looking at the exception using the debugger watch window actually prevents the exception from being rethrown. Would expain my confusion when trying to debug this. Enjoy your 300 points.

Comment: Now you got it. StackOverflow didn't allow me to immediately give the bounty after setting your reply as the correct answer. For some reason, I had to wait for like 3 hours first. Which happened to coincide with me logging of and leaving office. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me exactly which task is throwing the exception, but if it's one you control, you can simply add a continuation:

```
task.ContinueWith(t => {
    // Depending on t.Status (cancelled or faulted) you could perform logging
    // or whatever... presumably nothing's watching for the task to complete,
    // otherwise *it* would see the exception...
}, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion);
```

Of course if you can use .NET 4.5 and C# 5, async/await *may* help you - it depends on what SignalR does.

Comment: That's right, you Start() returns a task so you can do Start().ContinueWith(..)